# Using tables in other files

Tags: lua

**Edit** I got this working, I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, but this is what works right now

I just started learning Lua, and I'm trying to figure out how to pass tables between files so that I can have a more organized codespace. I have read through the book Programming in Lua, and for some reason, I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

The problem i'm getting is this error:

lua: Test2.lua:3: attempt to call method 'New' (a nil value)

From this code:

```
--Test.lua----------------
module("Test", package.seeall)
vector = require "./Hump/vector"

Bot = {}

Bot.position  =  vector.new(0,0)

function Bot:New(object)
    object = object or {}
    setmetatable(object, self)
    self.__index = self
    return object
end


--Test2.lua------------------
require "Test"

Bot1 = Test.Bot:New()

print(Bot1.position)
```

As far as I understand it, this error means that it cannot find the method new, it is effectively undefined. I thought that require imports the file in the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bot` is an empty table.

```
local B = {} -- initialize local B with new table
Bot = B -- Bot now references the same table as B

B = { position = vector.new(0,0) } -- here you create a NEW table, B ~= Bot now

function B:New(object) -- store New function in B table, Bot still empty
```

So you're returning an empty table.

No need for two variables here at all.

```
local Bot = {
    -- stuff
}

function Bot:New(object)
    -- stuff
end

return Bot
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that line 3 should really be B.position = 0, after some research I got this working using module("Test", package.seeall) is this correct way to get around this problem?

Comment: If you got it working then you made changes beyond that, because in the code you posted, `Bot` is an empty table. You also should set the `__index =` on `Bot` itself, since it's the metatable. And you don't want `position =` in `Bot`, unless this is supposed to be a class variable (i.e. same for all instances of `Bot`). If position is unique state for each `Bot` instance, then you need to initialize for the object in the `Bot` constructor.

Comment: My plan was to make position a class variable for all of type Bot, yes. What's the different between self.__index = self and self.__index = Bot?

Comment: What do you mean by Initialize for the object in the Bot constructor?

Comment: You can say `Bot.__index = Bot` outside of the constructor, then you're only doing it once. It's pointless to set the same field to the same value ever time the constructor is called.

Comment: By "Bot constructor" I mean `Bot:New`. This is called a constructor because it's used to construct a new instance of the `Bot` class. In it, you create a new table, set it's metatable to `Bot` and return it.  That new table (object, instance, whatever) needs it's own copy of `position`. Right now, you have only one `position` variable, in the `Bot` class itself.